# How to get actual minute in Amazon AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I try code my first Alexa Skill by using an Amazon AWS Lambda function. Therefore I need the EXACT minute when the function is called. Right now I am creating a new Date object. But it looks like Amazon just calls the function one time for some minutes. When I log the time to the console it logs for example 17:29 when the function was invoked first. And then 17:29 when the function is invoked later and it‘s actual 17:32. After some minutes this begins from beginning.
How can I get the actual minute when the function is called?

Greetings
Julian

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sounds like you have a cold vs. warm start issue.  As @Jack said post some code to help.

Comment: CloudWatch logs the start/stop timestamps for each lambda call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your date object initialization inside your handler function. Right now you are initializing it only once when the function is deployed to the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the Alexa Skills Kit, you can get the exact timestamp of when Alexa sent the request to your lambda function by retrieving it from request object.

From the documentation:

> timestamp
>   Provides the date and time when Alexa sent the request as an ISO 8601 formatted string

Depending on your use case this may be your preferred timestamp, since an end user is directly interacting with your lambda function by way of Alexa.

### Further Reading

- [Alexa Documentation - Request Types Reference (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest, SessionEndedRequest)](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-standard-request-types-reference) - Includes example syntax.
- [Alexa Documentation - Request Body Parameters](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#request-body-parameters) - Container object for your request, includes some helpful context and request body syntax.